# Custom wp_query time filter on meta_value

Tags: filters, wp-query, post-meta

My goal is to only show posts with opening hours after business hours, for a given day. So, e.g. I have a (custom) post with following meta_key and meta_value:

meta_key = 'monday, meta_value = '14:00 - 22:00'

The business hours  are fixed: '08:00 - 18:00'

I'd like to add a filter to my custom wp_query. Only, I am getting stuck at defining a function.

My logic input (definitely not correct & complete) for the function:

```
$from_std = strtotime("08:00");
$to_std = strtotime("18:00");                   

$open = $my_meta['monday'];
list($from, $hyphen, $to) = explode(' ', $open);
$from_bus = strtotime($from); 
$to_bus = strtotime($to);

if ($from_bus < $from_std) { $show = 1; } // before standard starting time - so SHOW
  else {if ($to_bus > $to_std) { $show = 1; }} // after standard closing time - so SHOW

if (empty($from_bus)) { show = 0; } // $var is either 0, empty, or not set at all - so do NOT show
```

Help on a function is very much appreciated.

Comment: strtotime is not that helpful for what you're trying to do. compare http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php . instead you can just do a string compare because `'00:00' < '00:30' < '01:00'` and so on. just ensure those values are following the same format.

Comment: OK, that would be more efficient then. Thanks for pointing that out. Could you give me directions with translating this into a function with a where-filter?

Comment: What is a where-filter? You want to convert that into a SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the WP query_posts to filter about your custom values; ean example:

```
query_posts('meta_key=my_type&meta_compare=<=&my_value=20&orderby=my_value');
if (have_posts()) :
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

But, i think you must replace the time-values for readable string, maybe woth strotime, that you have the same format for the query.

Comment: thanks - that's how it worked out for me. However in the end I set up things differently. The main problem was that opening hours were recorded passing a day limit. So e.g. open from 22:00 - 05.00. I tried some nifty logic on this - but the results were never 100% correct. Now, I leave it up to human interpretation if a business is open after office hours by indicating if that is not the case. Now the results are 100% correct - leaving human errors out.

Comment: @Henk jan: maybe you can add your solution here and we see on the code of the timestamp. Its usefull for all readers and maybe you become an better solution.